# Which Hindu texts contains the story of Santoshi Mata and about her other legends?

Tags: belief, goddess, santoshi

I checked wikipedia and according to it there is no scriptual reference of Santoshi Mata in Hindu texts and she just gained popularity after 1960 movie 'Jai Santoshi Maa'. After reading the wiki article it seems as if she is a self created new goddess. Can somebody please explain which hindu texts contains the story of Santoshi Mata and about her other legends ?

Comment: Yes, it is true that there is absolutely no record of Santhoshi Maa before the 1960's, and then she was popularized by the 1975 movie.

Comment: No, Santoshi Mata is not Hindu goddess. She is just production of a movie for sure. The movie was released on Friday so woman used to fast on Friday :) it is really funny but it is really true.

Comment: @Vipul Actually Santhoshi Mata was worshipped for 15 years before the movie was made, although the movie is what popularized her. But yeah, there's no record of her before the 1960's.

Answer (score -2):

This is a clear indication that Kaliyuga incarnations of God are available today to fight the necessary evils on earth. **Such an incarnation of supreme valour is Maa Santoshi**. That's why, learned persons only recommend understanding, reading mainly SRIMAD BHAGWAD GITA, as it's the essence of all other Scriptures.

In [BHAGWAD GITA](https://www.gitasupersite.iitk.ac.in/srimad?language=dv&field_chapter_value=10&field_nsutra_value=34&etssa=1&choose=1), Krishna doesn't mention any Goddess name at all, he simply mentioned once that-

Among women I am fame, fortune, speech, memory, intelligence, faithfulness and patience.

> मृत्युः सर्वहरश्चाहमुद्भवश्च भविष्यताम्।
>
> कीर्तिः श्रीर्वाक्च नारीणां स्मृतिर्मेधा धृतिः क्षमा।।10.34।।
>
> I am the Death that carries away all and also the Birth of all that
> are to be born; among women, I am the Fame, Fortune, Speech,
> Memory, Wisdom, Constancy and Patience.

Here, women denotes-- DEVI MAA

Here,
**Patience-- denotes 'Santosh'- one of the qualities MAA SANTOSHI bestows on her devotees.
Other Goddess too can be observed in the above verse--
Speech- bestowed by MAA SARASWATI
Fortune- bestowed by MAA LAKSHMI
Fame(power,status)- bestowed by MAA KALIKA**

**Also, Sri Krishna tells among all intonations mantra, he is the Gayatri mantra.**

Comment: You have to quote references for the answers provided in this site.  In respect of this answer, I have provided the reference.  By the way, the Gita sloka, which you are referring to may not be answering the question.  Please check again.

Comment: SRIMAD BHAGWAD GITA is the only authentic eternal knowledge source- as it's God gifted - (latest Sri krishna revived this eternal knowledge to Arjuna and was passed down as it is through succession of saints) while other innumerable sources are outcomes of meditations, thus, created by saints based on their level of expertise.

Comment: There's no mention of any Santoshi word even, let alone Devi Santoshi. This is not an answer.

Comment: She's present time necessity accepting worship 'Kaliyuga avtar' as based on necessity God's descend for example Rajasthan has many Kaliyuga avtar of God's like: Ramdev Pir https://www.google.com/amp/s/www.patrika.com/jaisalmer-news/history-of-baba-ramdev-ji-peero-ka-peer-3410460/%3famp=1 ; 
 He's our savior and present Vishnuji along with Tirupati Balaji in South https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ramdev_Pir

Comment: @SaurabhTJain Ramsa pir being avataar of Vishnu is found only in 
the bhajans sung by Harji bhati, Rawal maal, Tolla de 
& Rani Rupa de. Other than that I doubt if there is any mention of him being Dwarkadhish himself by other contemporary saints of that time. Incase if you have more ref to it, please attach the link in comment, tht will be alot helpfull.

Comment: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ramdev_Pir