# Is there any mention or description of Karwachauth in Hindu scriptures?

Tags: festivals

**Please provide a description of why Karwachauth is celebrated.** 
As far as I know, there is some story about fasting by a woman and due to her mistake ( in not doing the fasts properly, she mistook a *diya* as the moon), her husband dies. So, Karwachauth maata tells her to take fast on a day which we, Hindus, now celebrate as Karwachauth.

Comment: It cannot be Santoshi mata as there is no reference of Santoshi mata in any scriptures and she became popular only after the movie. See http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/5300/1018

Comment: On the other side, we generally see Shiv parivar photos on the Karvachauth poster photos so i think she must be a form of Goddess Parvati.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Yes.

The [Narada Purana (Part IV)](https://archive.org/stream/dli.bengal.10689.12976#page/n109/mode/2up) has an entire section dedicated to performance on vratas on different tithis.

In the section of different vratas to be performed on the Chathurti Tithis, there is a rite known as Karaka Vrata observed on the 4th in the dark half of Karttika.

> 43b-44 The holy rite called **Karaka vrata** is to be performed on **the Caturthi day in the dark half of the month of Karttika.** Only women are authorised to perform this Vrata. The rules of the procedure on it are being mentioned.
>
> 44b-45 The woman should take her bath and bedeck herself. She should then worship god Ganesa. **In front of the deity ten bowls filled with cooked rice shall be kept** and be dedicated to the Lord of the Devas with devotion and purity of the mind.
>
> 46-47 She should utter (pray) :--"May the deity be gracious unto me." Saying this she should dedicate them to God Ganesa.
>   **Presents shall be given respectfully to Suvasinis (married women) and the Brahmanas according to desire. Then at night, when the moon rises, she should duly offer Arghya (water oblation) and partake of sweet-meats and cooked rice for the fulfilment of the Vrata.**
>
> 50-51a Or the holy rite shall be observed by the woman throughout her life with a desire for conjugal blessedness. **There is no other Vrata like this that yields conjugal blessedness to women.** Hence it should be continuously performed.

According to what I read on [this website](http://www.karwachauth.com/karwa-chauth-puja.html) on Karwa Chauth, it is indeed that the same festival is described in the Purana.

The Sanskrit verses have been taken [from here (page 849)](http://vedicreserve.mum.edu/puranas/narada_purana_purva.pdf)

[image]

Hope this helped.

Comment: Good answer. You can also mention about info.given in other puranas, as footnote says in the link picture provided by you.Also try to provide links directly to authentic scriptures like Puranas whenever possible, instead of providing the passage as image.

Comment: All right I will do further research and put up the info found in other puranas as well :) I normally do link directly to the Purana source but since I got this info from DSpace's Narada Purana I had to go a roundabout way to upload it.

Comment: You are quoting sentences from multiple chapters/vratas of [Narada Purana (Part IV)](https://archive.org/details/dli.bengal.10689.12976/page/n143) giving the impression that all the steps belong to the same procedure. First sentence is from [pg. 1477](https://archive.org/details/dli.bengal.10689.12976/page/n143), the rest are from [pg. 1445](https://archive.org/details/dli.bengal.10689.12976/page/n111), that is why we need to avoid copy-pasting from blogs.

Comment: So karwachauth has nothing to do with longevity of husbands?

Comment: @sv. No, OP quoted from page 1444 and continued to 1445. See from 43b-44 to 50-51. Just skipped 2 verses in between.

Comment: @Arya thanks for this answer

Comment: @Carmensandiego I am assuming that the longevity of husbands comes as a corollary from the desire for 'conjugal' blessedness. Would be helpful if we know what the original verse says.

Comment: @Arya do you have access to the original Sanskrit work? Can you check what exactly is mentioned for conjugal blessedness in the original text?

Comment: @Sarvabhouma You're right. I was confused by "The holy rite called Karaka vrata is to be performed on the Caturthi day..." also listed under Ch. 117 "Vratas to be observed on Ashtami" on pg. 1477.

Comment: @Dr.VineetAggarwal Hi I've attached a photo of the Sanskrit verses, if there's anyone here that could translate I would appreciate it since I don't know Sanskrit. AFAIK, verse 50 photo refers to the ritual conferring "saubhagya" and in Sanskrit unwidowed women are known as "saubhagyavati" so it could mean that Karaka vrata ensures the long life of the husband. Yet this only a conjecture. :)

Comment: @Arya - wouldn't that be 'sada suhagan raho' ? I think 'saubhagyavati bhava' means wish you a a happy married life or conjugal blessedness

Comment: @Arya thanks for that addition. Sau-bhagya basically means Good-Bhagya or Fortune/Luck so I guess we can say that a married woman is lucky if her husband doesn't die but still it is only indirectly referring to the husband not directly. This implies the Karva Chauth is basically for a good life of the wife and not really the longevity of the husband,

Comment: Why do they see the moon through a sieve or see the reflection of moon in water but do not see it directly? Is there any reference to it in the Purana or any text?

Comment: The footnote in the link provided in this answer refers to Vamana purana where I understand Gauri puja is mentioned. Anyone got link to the Vamana Purana section?