# Do any scriptures talk about Atla Taddi?

Tags: festivals

Today is Karva Chauth (Chaturthi) celebrated in the north especially Punjab and I found out that Telugu people also celebrate the Uma Vratham or [Atla Taddi [(https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atla_Tadde) on the Tritiya. Both of them are related to marriage so I was wondering if there is any scriptures (not local stories) that mention these festivals?

[Is there any mention or description of Karwachauth in Hindu scriptures?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/9256/5212) contains information about Karva Chauth only. My question also asks about Atla Taddi celebrated on Tritiya. Hence not a duplicate.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there any mention or description of Karwachauth in Hindu scriptures?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/9256/is-there-any-mention-or-description-of-karwachauth-in-hindu-scriptures)

Comment: Since this question also covers about Atla Taddi which is a different festival than Karva Chauth, question is not an exact duplicate. It's a partial duplicate. I edited the question to make it clear about references about Atla taddi.

Comment: Thank you @Sarvabhouma for the edit